# SSL Certification Issue - Spring and Local Self-Signed Certificate with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl, spring-security, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to set up a development environment using CAS/Spring, but I'm running into a certificate issue.

UPDATE: Forgot to update this, but this is the error I'm getting now.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:328)
    org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:291)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:32)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider.authenticateNow(CasAuthenticationProvider.java:140)
    org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CasAuthenticationProvider.java:126)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(CasAuthenticationFilter.java:242)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

This is my Tomcat server.xml section that deals with my certificate:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" keystoreFile="C:\Users\MyStuff\certs\mykeystore.jks" keystorePass="changeit" truststoreFile="C:\Users\MyStuff\certs\mykeystore.jks" truststorePass="changeit" clientAuth="want" sslProtocol="TLS" ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA" />
```

The only certificate in mykeystore.jks is:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            c9:76:d9:5e:50:b3:97:59
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=DC, L=DC, O=GU, OU=people, CN=www.testthisout.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 12 20:00:22 2015 GMT
            Not After : Mar 11 20:00:22 2025 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=DC, L=DC, O=GU, OU=people, CN=www.testthisout.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (1024 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:e7:e7:0b:e7:0f:28:a4:dd:7c:e8:79:51:82:a9:
                    c1:0d:fc:54:ea:63:6f:d0:34:dc:d7:a0:be:a7:90:
                    87:0e:7b:00:96:84:f5:30:70:20:db:8a:e8:22:55:
                    a4:c4:8a:bc:1b:16:08:a9:65:55:19:aa:f9:7c:9e:
                    04:92:73:ed:72:ac:83:76:ae:6d:cd:65:9e:f3:7a:
                    ba:d9:51:29:8f:a9:89:49:b3:b3:31:a9:1b:da:bb:
                    1e:b0:90:2a:6e:d1:1a:42:ff:a6:33:2e:bd:4d:05:
                    b6:af:35:7b:b2:de:eb:69:95:46:67:6a:a9:b6:f1:
                    3a:3b:e2:55:02:1f:8c:85:37
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                FE:F2:87:D8:2F:1B:25:A4:C1:77:D9:D8:84:C9:D8:F0:3C:F5:15:E2
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:FE:F2:87:D8:2F:1B:25:A4:C1:77:D9:D8:84:C9:D8:F0:3C:F5:15:E
2

            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        01:da:af:b0:0b:1b:1a:4d:75:5b:af:4f:98:72:04:12:9a:d6:
        47:af:16:49:72:9f:37:ee:71:69:0f:f8:a4:a0:d8:3e:e0:fb:
        87:f4:3d:29:90:46:f6:28:5e:e5:85:e7:af:f4:2c:f4:cb:06:
        7d:ce:2c:74:a7:35:f8:43:da:ec:69:4a:33:47:33:1c:0a:ec:
        5d:1d:7c:93:bd:8f:e5:f9:6d:3d:af:c4:31:47:6d:e7:ae:76:
        c4:c2:64:f2:9e:d5:56:ff:04:59:48:30:f4:25:3f:b7:ab:2a:
        25:12:5c:17:5c:ef:77:1f:b1:64:18:6b:21:02:bf:2a:11:1e:
        ea:e3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

You can see my CN=www.testthisout.com

So in my hosts file I've added:

127.0.0.1   www.testthisout.com

When I launch go to my Web app (https://www.testthisout.com:443/CASTest), I get the above error. Not sure why it is coming up.

EDIT: Here is CAS's deployerConfigContext.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encTestg="UTF-8"?>
<!--

    Licensed to Jasig under one or more contributor license
    agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work
    for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    Jasig licenses this file to you under the Apache License,
    Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file
    except in compliance with the License.  You may obtain a
    copy of the License at the following location:

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
    KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.

-->
<!--
        | deployerConfigContext.xml centralizes into one file some of the declarative configuration that
        | all CAS deployers will need to modify.
        |
        | This file declares some of the Spring-managed JavaBeans that make up a CAS deployment.
        | The beans declared in this file are instantiated at context initialization time by the Spring
        | ContextLoaderListener declared in web.xml.  It finds this file because this
        | file is among those declared in the context parameter "contextConfigLocation".
        |
        | By far the most common change you will need to make in this file is to change the last bean
        | declaration to replace the default SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler with
        | one implementing your approach for authenticating usernames and passwords.
        +-->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
        <!--
                | This bean declares our AuthenticationManager.  The CentralAuthenticationService service bean
                | declared in applicationContext.xml picks up this AuthenticationManager by reference to its id,
                | "authenticationManager".  Most deployers will be able to use the default AuthenticationManager
                | implementation and so do not need to change the class of this bean.  We include the whole
                | AuthenticationManager here in the userConfigContext.xml so that you can see the things you will
                | need to change in context.
                +-->
        <bean id="authenticationManager"
                class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl">

                <!-- Uncomment the metadata populator to allow clearpass to capture and cache the password
                     This switch effectively will turn on clearpass.
                <property name="authenticationMetaDataPopulators">
                   <list>
                      <bean class="org.jasig.cas.extension.clearpass.CacheCredentialsMetaDataPopulator">
                         <constructor-arg index="0" ref="credentialsCache" />
                      </bean>
                   </list>
                </property>
                 -->

                <!--
                        | This is the List of CredentialToPrincipalResolvers that identify what Principal is trying to authenticate.
                        | The AuthenticationManagerImpl considers them in order, finding a CredentialToPrincipalResolver which
                        | supports the presented credentials.
                        |
                        | AuthenticationManagerImpl uses these resolvers for two purposes.  First, it uses them to identify the Principal
                        | attempting to authenticate to CAS /login .  In the default configuration, it is the DefaultCredentialsToPrincipalResolver
                        | that fills this role.  If you are using some other kind of credentials than UsernamePasswordCredentials, you will need to replace
                        | DefaultCredentialsToPrincipalResolver with a CredentialsToPrincipalResolver that supports the credentials you are
                        | using.
                        |
                        | Second, AuthenticationManagerImpl uses these resolvers to identify a service requesting a proxy granting ticket.
                        | In the default configuration, it is the HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver that serves this purpose.
                        | You will need to change this list if you are identifying services by something more or other than their callback URL.
                        +-->
                <property name="credentialsToPrincipalResolvers">
                        <list>
                                <!--
                                        | UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver supports the UsernamePasswordCredentials that we use for /login
                                        | by default and produces SimplePrincipal instances conveying the username from the credentials.
                                        |
                                        | If you've changed your LoginFormAction to use credentials other than UsernamePasswordCredentials then you will also
                                        | need to change this bean declaration (or add additional declarations) to declare a CredentialsToPrincipalResolver that supports the
                                        | Credentials you are using.
                                        +-->
                                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver" >
                                        <property name="attributeRepository" ref="attributeRepository" />
                                </bean>
                                <!--
                                        | HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver supports HttpBasedCredentials.  It supports the CAS 2.0 approach of
                                        | authenticating services by SSL callback, extracting the callback URL from the Credentials and representing it as a
                                        | SimpleService identified by that callback URL.
                                        |
                                        | If you are representing services by something more or other than an HTTPS URL whereat they are able to
                                        | receive a proxy callback, you will need to change this bean declaration (or add additional declarations).
                                        +-->
                                <bean
                                        class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver" />
                        </list>
                </property>

                <!--
                        | Whereas CredentialsToPrincipalResolvers identify who it is some Credentials might authenticate,
                        | AuthenticationHandlers actually authenticate credentials.  Here we declare the AuthenticationHandlers that
                        | authenticate the Principals that the CredentialsToPrincipalResolvers identified.  CAS will try these handlers in turn
                        | until it finds one that both supports the Credentials presented and succeeds in authenticating.
                        +-->
                <property name="authenticationHandlers">
                        <list>
                                <!--
                                        | This is the authentication handler that authenticates services by means of callback via SSL, thereby validating
                                        | a server side SSL certificate.
                                        +-->
                                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler"
                                        p:httpClient-ref="httpClient" />
                                <!--
                                        | This is the authentication handler declaration that every CAS deployer will need to change before deploying CAS
                                        | into production.  The default SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler authenticates UsernamePasswordCredentials
                                        | where the username equals the password.  You will need to replace this with an AuthenticationHandler that implements your
                                        | local authentication strategy.  You might accomplish this by cTestg a new such handler and declaring
                                        | com.someschool.its.cas.MySpecialHandler here, or you might use one of the handlers provided in the adaptors modules.
                                        +-->
                                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler">
                                        <property name="filter" value="uid=%u" />
                                        <property name="searchBase"
                                                value="ou=people,dc=test,dc=com" />
                                        <property
                                                name="contextSource"
                                                ref="contextSource" />
                                </bean>


                                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler">
                                    <property name="tableUsers"><value>users</value></property>
                                    <property name="fieldUser"><value>id</value></property>
                                    <property name="fieldPassword"><value>password</value></property>
                                    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
                                  </bean>



                        </list>
                </property>
        </bean>

                <bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
                <property name="anonymousReadOnly" value="false" />
                <property name="pooled" value="true" />
                <property name="password" value="50Z1xpUdS64fT18NIz20m3XAy4U" />
                <property name="urls">
                        <list>
                                <value>ldaps://directory.test.com:636</value>
                        </list>
                </property>
                <property name="userDn" value="uid=TestAdmin,ou=Specials,dc=test,dc=com" />
                <property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
                        <map>
                        <entry>
                        <key><value>java.naming.security.protocol</value></key>
                        <value>ssl</value>
                        </entry>
                                <entry>
                                        <key><value>java.naming.security.authentication</value></key>
                                        <value>simple</value>
                                </entry>
                        </map>
                </property>
        </bean>

          <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName">
                <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
            </property>
            <property name="url">
                <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_mgt</value>
            </property>
            <property name="username"><value>root</value></property>
            <property name="password"><value>apollo</value></property>
        </bean>

        <!--
        This bean defines the security roles for the Services Management application.  Simple deployments can use the in-memory version.
        More robust deployments will want to use another option, such as the Jdbc version.

        The name of this should remain "userDetailsService" in order for Spring Security to find it.
         -->
    <!-- <sec:user name="@@THIS SHOULD BE REPLACED@@" password="notused" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />-->

    <sec:user-service id="userDetailsService">
        <sec:user name="@@THIS SHOULD BE REPLACED@@" password="notused" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    </sec:user-service>

        <!--
        Bean that defines the attributes that a service may return.  This example uses the Stub/Mock version.  A real implementation
        may go against a database or LDAP server.  The id should remain "attributeRepository" though.
         -->
        <bean id="attributeRepository"
                class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.StubPersonAttributeDao">
                <property name="backingMap">
                        <map>
                                <entry key="uid" value="uid" />
                                <entry key="comPersonAffiliation" value="comPersonAffiliation" />
                                <entry key="groupMembership" value="groupMembership" />
                        </map>
                </property>
        </bean>

        <!--
        Sample, in-memory data store for the ServiceRegistry. A real implementation
        would probably want to replace this with the JPA-backed ServiceRegistry DAO
        The name of this bean should remain "serviceRegistryDao".
         -->
        <bean
                id="serviceRegistryDao"
        class="org.jasig.cas.services.InMemoryServiceRegistryDaoImpl">
            <property name="registeredServices">
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService">
                        <property name="id" value="0" />
                        <property name="name" value="HTTP and IMAP" />
                        <property name="description" value="Allows HTTP(S) and IMAP(S) protocols" />
                        <property name="serviceId" value="^(https?|imaps?)://.*" />
                        <property name="evaluationOrder" value="10000001" />
                    </bean>
                    <!--
                    Use the following definition instead of the above to further restrict access
                    to services within your domain (including subdomains).
                    Note that example.com must be replaced with the domain you wish to permit.
                    -->
                    <!--
                    <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService">
                        <property name="id" value="1" />
                        <property name="name" value="HTTP and IMAP on example.com" />
                        <property name="description" value="Allows HTTP(S) and IMAP(S) protocols on example.com" />
                        <property name="serviceId" value="^(https?|imaps?)://([A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.)*example\.com/.*" />
                        <property name="evaluationOrder" value="0" />
                    </bean>
                    -->
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

  <bean id="auditTrailManager" class="com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager" />

  <bean id="healthCheckMonitor" class="org.jasig.cas.monitor.HealthCheckMonitor">
    <property name="monitors">
      <list>
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.monitor.MemoryMonitor"
            p:freeMemoryWarnThreshold="10" />
        <!--
          NOTE
          The following ticket registries support SessionMonitor:
            * DefaultTicketRegistry
            * JpaTicketRegistry
          Remove this monitor if you use an unsupported registry.
        -->
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.monitor.SessionMonitor"
            p:ticketRegistry-ref="ticketRegistry"
            p:serviceTicketCountWarnThreshold="5000"
            p:sessionCountWarnThreshold="100000" />
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

EDIT: This

Comment: Your question seems to be describing the setup for your client application, but the exception is from your client's call to the CAS server. Where is the CAS server running and what certificate is it using?

Comment: I'm running CAS on the same Tomcat instance, locally on my machine. So it is also using the same certificate, with a URL of https://www.testthisout.com:443/cas-server-webapp-3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that setting `truststore` on a Tomcat connector only applies to checking client certificates for the SSL connnections coming in on that connector.

Try setting the truststore globally for the VM, adding `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` to the `CATALINA_OPTS` or `JAVA_OPTS` environment variables, or add your certificate to the local `cacerts` file.

Comment: I've tried both and unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. I added my cert to cacerts in my JAVA_HOME directory, and my JAVA_OPTS is set to this in catalina.bat : -DJavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Users\Adam\certs\mykeystore.jks"-DJavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="changeit" -Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\xampp\tomcat\conf\logging.properties"-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager

Comment: I'm not sure why you would get this error with the setup you describe, but since it's complaining about missing "subject alternative names" you could try adding that extension to your certificate. You can find guides on that online, like [this one](http://apetec.com/support/GenerateSAN-CSR.htm).

Comment: You should probably also post your CAS client configuration. That error usually only seems to occur when an IP address is used rather than the server name. You are sure you're not doing that?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've updated my question with my deployerConfigContext.xml file for CAS.

Comment: Also updated the error I'm getting. You're right that I was getting that error before due to an IP address, but since I've switched to the host name I've been getting a different error.